# Building Jfxtras on OSX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, gradle, jfxtras, gradlew

This is driving me crazy. I am trying to build the jfxtras using the gradlew build command. and I am getting the following error

```
Please set environment variable JAVAFX_HOME to the directory that contains /rt/lib/jfxrt.jar for JavaFX version 2.1.0
```

My machine is OSX, and the my path to jfxrt.jar is

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext
```

however the build error above calls for the .jar at /rt/lib/ not /jre/lib/ext

any solutions out there for the mac users.

Comment: Thanks, I just did some research about this symlink. however how do I establish this in my case. how can I make `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext` equal `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/rt/lib/`

Comment: I get the following  ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/rt/lib/
`ln: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/rt/lib/: No such file or directory`

Comment: `mkdir -p /some/dir/rt/lib/`, `ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar /some/dir/rt/lib/jfxrt.jar`, and set `JAVAFX_HOME` to `/some/dir/` (at least for the Gradle process). If that doesn't work, find out who is responsible for the "please set environment variable" message, and contact them.

Comment: Thanks mate, I did all above but still same error. how do I check that the JAVAFX_HOME has been set to the correct path. btw I am using the Environment Variables Program to set this path